# Installing foreman on a different node than Puppet master?

Tags: puppet, theforeman

Is it possible to install foreman on a different node than a Puppet master? If yes, are there any things which needs to be taken care.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to [install a smart proxy](http://theforeman.org/manuals/1.7/index.html#4.3SmartProxies) on the same machine as the puppet master, which will then allow foreman to manage it.